# Lua scripts in scrapy

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm working with scrapy 1.6 and splash 3.2 I have:

```
import scrapy
import random
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):


    start_urls = ["http://yahoo.com"]
    name = 'mytest'

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint='render.html', args={'wait': 2.5},headers={'User-Agent': USER_AGENT,'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'})

    def parse(self, response):
        # response.body is a result of render.html call; it
        # contains HTML processed by a browser.
        # from scrapy.http.response.html import HtmlResponse
        # ht = HtmlResponse('jj')
        # ht.body.replace =response
        open_in_browser(response)
        return None
```

I'm reading through https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash and in this they give the example of:

```
function main(splash)
assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
splash:wait(0.5)
local title = splash:evaljs("document.title")
return {title=title}
end
```

Obviously I can't put Lua in my python script. Where do I put it and how do I access it to pass to my splash request?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908191/scrapy-splash-wont-execute-lua-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the lua script as a string like this:

```
script = """
    function main(splash)
        assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
        splash:wait(0.5)
        local title = splash:evaljs('document.title')
        return {title=title}
    end
"""
yield SplashRequest(
    url, self.parse, endpoint='render.html',
    args={'wait': 2.5, 'lua_source': script},
    headers={'User-Agent': USER_AGENT,'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}
)
```

Check the docs for scrapy-splash: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash